# Vectorized way of finding the index of a previously occurring element

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Let's say I have this Pandas series:

`num = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5,6,5,6,4,2,1,3])`

What I want to do is to get a number, say 5, and return the index where it previously occurred. So if I'm using the element 5, I should get 4 as the element appears in indices 4 and 6. Now I want to do this for all of the elements of the series, and can be easily done using a for loop:

```
for idx,x in enumerate(num):
        idx_prev = num[num == x].idxmax()
        if(idx_prev < idx):
                return idx_prev
```

However, this process consumes too much time for longer series lengths due to the looping. Is there a way to implement the same thing but in a vectorized form? The output should be something like this:

`[NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,4,5,3,1,0,2]`

Comment: Please add the expected output.

Comment: Edited to show the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `groupby` to shift the index:

```
num.index.to_series().groupby(num).shift()
```

Output:

```
0     NaN
1     NaN
2     NaN
3     NaN
4     NaN
5     NaN
6     4.0
7     5.0
8     3.0
9     1.0
10    0.0
11    2.0
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to keep working in `numpy`.

Equivalent of `[num[num == x].idxmax() for idx,x in enumerate(num)]` using `numpy` is:

`_, out = np.unique(num.values, return_inverse=True)`

which assigns

`array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 3, 1, 0, 2], dtype=int64)`

to `out`. Now you can assign bad values of `out` to `Nan`s like this:

```
out_series = pd.Series(out)
out_series[out >= np.arange(len(out))] = np.nan
```